# Android app is continuously crashing while implementing the android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I was trying to implement the BottomNavigationView in my android app but while implementing it, the app is crashing continuously.

**reader_settings_dialog.xml**

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/annotations"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_48"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_48"
   android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

**ReadersSettings.java**

```
@Overrride
public void onClick(View v){
   if (v.getId() == R.id.annotations) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AnnotationsActivity.class);
     getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

When a user will click on the respective image, another XML file will AnnotationsActivity class will call.

**AnnotationActivity.java**

```
public class AnnotationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.annotation_parent_imp);
    }
}
```

**annotation_parent_imp.xml**

```
<include
        layout="@layout/annotationsparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**annotationsparent.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_menu_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_menu_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
```

ideally on click of that image this Activity should be open with bottom navigation implemented in it but my app is crashing and throwing an error

*Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-rc03] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-28:19 to override.*

**bottom_navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_dashboard"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="Highlight" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_explore"
      android:title="Notes"/>
     <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_report"
      android:title="Bookmark"/>
</menu>
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

please help me with this
thanks in advance !!!

Comment: It seems that you are mixing androidx and support libraries.

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti, sorry but what androidX and where to add that ??

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: I am already posted that one.
Not a complete file but all required dependencies which I am using that I have shared in the post

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have updated my project in androidx but still, the app is crashing